# How to show reverse y axis of Zingchart in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zingchart

I am trying to implement Zingchart in Python and I want to show y axis in reverse order from top to bottom like -10, 0, 10,20.....120, and also trying to hide alternative line on x axis and show fixed labels on x axis. Does anyone know how to show y axis in reverse order and hide lines on x axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by setting mirrored:true in y axis like:

```
scale-y:
{
  label:{
  text:'Hearing Level',
},
  mirrored:true,
  minorTicks:1,
  values:'10:120:10',
  step:5
}
```

Comment: I think for this use case it would actually be scaleX